# Strange behaviour activity

Tags: android

Help me to find out the behaviour of activity. Sometimes during curtailing application and it's opening, the system returns result not to that activity, where it has been curtailed. It creates a new copy of the same activity. I have to notice, that during pressing abort button, opens previous activity. I mean activity is opened in application (let's call it A) we crectain it, open again and creates new activity A1 (the copy of A activity), during closing A1 we have an access to A. Such case happens to some cell phone models. If somebody has already had deal with such case please try to help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please extend what you mean with "Sometimes during curtailing application and it's opening, the system returns result not to that activity, where it has been curtailed." ? What do you do when you're saying that you "crectain" an Activity?

Comment: We need your code to answer, if you do something like : 

Intent intent = getIntent();
startActivity(intent);
finish();

to refresh your activity content on onStart() or onResume(), this kind of behavior could happen.... but again we can't say without your code

Answer (score 0):

If you want a certain behaviour, you have to specify it via [`android:launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) in your manifest or [`flags`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29) for Intent

Answer (score 0):

I start all my activities like this:

Intent intent = new Intent(Context, Class);

//

add extras

//

startActivityForResult(intent, ID); or startActivtiy(intent);

Activity sometimes imposed onto itself, when i back to the application